# How to use Mechanize to click on a link to scrape more details of an order?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

While on the orders index page I'm iterating over all the singleOrder's (http://pastebin.com/FtiTBXG4). What I want to do is click on each single order link to be able to parse more information about the order.

But the click or the iterations doesn't seem to be working. It just keeps clicking on the first order.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new

a.get('http://exampleshop.nl/admin/') do |page|

    # Select the login form
    login_form = page.forms.first

    # Insert the username and password
    login_form.username = 'username'
    login_form.password = 'password'

    # Submit the login information
    dashboard_page = a.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)

    # Check if the login was successfull
    puts check_1 = dashboard_page.title == 'Dashboard' ?  "CHECK 1 DASHBOARD SUCCESS" : "CHECK 1 DASHBOARD FAIL"

    # Visit the orders index page to scrape some standard information
    orders_page = a.click(dashboard_page.link_with(:text => /Bestellingen/))

    # pp orders_page # => http://pastebin.com/L3zASer6

    # Check if the visit is successful
    puts check_2 = orders_page.title == 'Bestellingen' ?  "CHECK 2 ORDERS SUCCESS" : "CHECK 2 ORDERS FAIL"

    # Search for all #singleOrder table row's and put them in variable all_single_orders
    all_single_orders = orders_page.search("#singleOrder") 

    # puts all_single_orders.class  # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
    # puts all_single_orders                # => http://pastebin.com/FtiTBXG4
    # pp all_single_orders                  # => http://pastebin.com/UMRxGDn2

    # Scrape the needed information (the actual save to database is omitted)
    all_single_orders.each do |order|
        # Fetch the standard information
        puts orderId = order.search("#orderId").text                # => 259    
        puts customerName = order.search("#customerName").text      # => Firstname Lastname     
        puts orderStatus = order.search("#orderStatus").text        # => Bestelling ontvangen           
        puts orderAmount = order.search("#orderAmount").text            # => € 41,94

        # pp order # => sample of a a single `order` iteration: http://pastebin.com/FkM8DVT8

        # Visit a single order page to fetch more detailed information
        single_order_page = orders_page.link_with(:text => /Bekijk/).click

        # puts single_order_page.class # => Mechanize::Page

        # Print the URI to check what page we're on
        puts single_order_page.uri # => http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=SOMETOKEN&order_id=259
    end
end
```

This is the output:

```
CHECK 1 DASHBOARD SUCCESS
CHECK 2 ORDERS SUCCESS
http://www.exampleshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=e29984974b56db4ba9d3c91a47d26f90&order_id=259
http://www.exampleshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=e29984974b56db4ba9d3c91a47d26f90&order_id=259
http://www.exampleshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=e29984974b56db4ba9d3c91a47d26f90&order_id=259
...
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Im using Ruby 2.0.0 and Mechanize 2.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
single_order_page = orders_page.link_with(:text => /Bekijk/).click
```

Here you are telling Mechanize to click the first link on the page with text "Bekijk". Note that this is looking for the first matching link on the **page** not just within the order (ie table row).

I think you will need to get the href of the link in the order and then click on the link with that href (or directly navigate to that link):

```
all_single_orders.each do |order|
    # Fetch the standard information
    puts orderLink = order.at_css("a")['href']  #Assuming first link in row

    # Visit a single order page to fetch more detailed information
    single_order_page = orders_page.link_with(:href => orderLink).click

    # Print the URI to check what page we're on
    puts single_order_page.uri # => http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&token=SOMETOKEN&order_id=259
end
```

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError` with the following message `in []': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`. I've updated the original question with what I did and the result. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, `search` returns a node set not the element. Changed the `search` to `at_css`.